# How to center both text and img in div

Tags: html, css

I have such html structure:

```
<div class="green">
  <img/>
  <p>
    text
  </p>
</div>
```

or such structure:

```
<div class="green">  
  <p class="red">
    <img/>
    text
  </p>
</div>
```

I display it here:

[image]

I tried styling like so:

```
.green {
  display: table;
}
p.red {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

but this is the result:

[image: rough sketch of expected style result]

```css
div {
  display: table;
  height: 140px;
  padding: 6px;
  margin: 18px;
}

p {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

img {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  float: right;
  width: 102px;
  height: 120px;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>
    <img src="/images/osteocenter_pozv.png">
    <span><strong>Заболевания позвоночника</strong>&nbsp;- серьезная проблема нашего времени: в последние два-три десятка лет они значительно помолодели и стали встречаться чаще.</span>
  </p>
</div>
```

How can I center both text and image?

Comment: Please post the relevant html markup and css styles.

Comment: It might seem that you use pading in your `<p>` or `<span>`. Provide your CSS and HTML

Comment: @FranciscoCarvalho http://jsfiddle.net/7AAwP/   see here... http://jsfiddle.net/7AAwP/

Comment: @Serv http://jsfiddle.net/7AAwP/

Answer (score 0):

use `display:inline` for text, and `vertical-align:middle` for image

see : http://jsfiddle.net/R6pns/

```css
img {
    vertical-align:middle;
}

p {
    display:inline;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <p>adfafdfsfffsdfasfdsfdf</p>
    <img src="/images/osteocenter_pozv.png" alt="" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all. 
But my solution was:

1. set image in other `<p>`
2. set this `<p>` after p with text
3. use `display: table-cell;`